# How can a parent class see the properties of its child class?

Tags: qt, properties, qobject

I'm doing some experiments on Qt. I try to read all properties annotated with Q_PROPERTY of a child class in its parent class. My classes look like this:

```
class ParentClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ParentProperty...)
    //class stuff...
}

class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ChildProperty...)
    //class stuff
}
```

Now I want to read all properties in the parent class, but I can only read the parent property. How can I get the properties of the child class? Is there a comfortable way for it?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Parent class should never know about child classes, so I'm comfident to say that there's a problem in your class design.

Comment: My intention was to create an easy to use database input/output system. So the user just have to define the properties(attributes) he want to store persistent in the database in his own class which inherits from the parent class where some attributes already defined. The parent class should read all properties of its child and build the tables with all properties as attributes. I could seperate it, but then the user have to register his own property class by his own.

Comment: Now what if the user doesn't want his subclass's attributes to be saved into the database? Or what if he's not even aware that the base class will access the subclass's properties? You should rather create a template method into the base class and then call it from subclass: `registerProperty<int>("height", &m_height);` or something similiar, depending on how your program works. But a basic rule is; **never** access subclass from base class. No exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You generally should not refer to any child class in your parent class. It breaks the idea of class inheritance.

If you sure that you need to do this, you should convert an object pointer to `ChildClass*` type and then use its properties.

```
void ParentClass::needToGoDeeper() {
  ChildClass* obj = qobject_cast<ChildClass*>(this);
  if (obj) {
    int count = obj->metaObject()->propertyCount();
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: How're you going to create a `ChildClass*` without including child class file, creating an include loop?

Comment: If you include 'ChildClass.h' in the top of 'ParentClass.cpp' (not 'ParentClass.h'), there will be no include loop.

Comment: Oh right, silly me. You still shouldn't advice anyone to do this, though.